# Posting the status updates on linkedin company profiles

Tags: linkedin-api

I am new to this feature of linkedin.How we can post the status on the company profile using the api provided by linkedin?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the LinkedIn's Company Share API http://developer.linkedin.com/creating-company-shares

You should use some library that handle the OAuth 2.0 authentication-authorization or take a look at http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples (if are able to understand code).

The process authorization process is simple - it redirects the user  (your company profile) to LinkedIn Signin page where he authorize your application and give you **Access Token**.
http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

Your Application with help of the Access Token could Share on company's page (linkedin profile)

The LinkedIn documentation contains a lot of information regarding OAuth 2.0 and Share details

Update: have found the usefull link. http://marketing.linkedin.com/company-pages/?scr=s-bl